# Graduation anniversary event?

Tags: discussion

I was poked by higher powers that February 14th is first anniversary of our graduation and we might want to celebrate in some way (example activity - [contest at SuperUser](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/)).

Sadly I am too busy and tired to meaningfully run this, so this needs both ideas and people to make them happen (with help from network of course).

Answer (score 1):

I could help out with part of this, probably the swag part, if someone else wants to come up with the contest rules and figure out who wins what.

We could delegate this to 3-4 people as I'm sure everyone is pretty busy, maybe it's a good idea to use the same format as superuser.

ps. I think this is a great idea to generate more users/answers and such.